# What to Consider when deciding whether to replicate or to distribute in order to support scalability?

Tags: architecture, scalability

When writing an application to support scalability, how do I decide whether to support it using technologies such as EJBs and distribute the application among multiple machines, or to write the software without using such technologies and just replicate it in multiple machines?

Are there any good resources (books/articles) that explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalability is more of an Architecture capability. Technologies and tools just realize this capability.

If you define your architecture inherently scalable, then you can retrofit any technologies to support the architecture. You can find examples out there which have scaled very well for large user base in almost all tech stacks ( be it PHP, .NET, Java, COBOL, RoR etc).

Since these days, it is cheap and easy to deploy on the cloud, design your architecture keeping in mind [Share Nothing architectural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture) concepts. You can easily scale on demand for any large userbase.

Coming to the specific technology which you have mentioned, EJB - it is an middleware technology and it comes with a baggage - Java EE Application Server (or Tomcat with some plumbing). The point is EJB solutions are not lightweight and are advised for specific use cases like - remotability, transactions etc etc. Plus the cost of developing standards based solutions is little on higher side then just using Open source stack.

From scalability point of view, standards based solutions i.e. EJB, JPA etc are also Cloud enabled and support Cloud scalability i.e. replicating and sharing. Check this [link](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/07/12/architectural-evolution-from-middleware-to-the-cloud).

With or without standards - what matter is the Application architecture which can scale.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is about vertical and horizontal scalability.

Ideally you should be thriving to achieve horizontal scalability, which is not easy.

Horizontal scalability has impact on architecture of your application, when vertical scalability requires you to add more horse power. We are currently in a position where we can easily scale vertically, but not horizontally. Our platform will simply peak in the coming months and we have to make changes to the platform's architecture.

I don't think this has something to do with any specific technology. You can use EJB and you still won't be able to scale horizontally. It's not as simple as that. There is a good book by Cal Henderson, Building Scalable Web Sites. Might be a good read to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Scalability is a broad term is generally technology agnostic.

If during your design phase you decide, I know this application is going to support 100k users, but I'd like to be able to support up to 1 Million users without a need to refactor, then you generally want to approach IMHO this sort of scaling through a "hardware" approach. If you know your design can handle 100k users fine on 2 servers in a cluster, reaching 1 Million can be reached through hardware increases, PROVIDED the software solution delivering that 100k base is not poorly designed.

Distributed technologies are interesting and nice, but they do have overhead, and problems that come with them.  Its not a big deal when your cluster only has 2 nodes, and you need a object from the other node, you know where that node is, and can go ask for it.. and that has a cost, but its usually not anything outrageous but when you scale that up to say now your cluster has 25 or 50 servers, getting that object, even if you have a nice container playing the traffic cop for it, can be an entirely different ball game.

Also, sad to say, but in the real world, management decision makers are often grossly technology ignorant, and tend to gravitate to the 9 women make a baby in a month mentality. Its a far easier battle for you to make, and for them honestly to comprehend to say, if you want that much more capacity we will need more hardware.. rather than well, it will need a complete refactor that could take 4-6 months.

With the hardware approach though, be well aware, its not infinite, there is overhead with every server you add to a cluster, and you do eventually reach the laws of diminishing returns.

My basic rule of thumb is as "neat" as it is to want to use all those fancy models that you read about, think long and hard to make sure they are the right solution, its very very easy to overarchitect a solution.